# How do calculate power consumed by a BLDC motor using two-wattmeter method

Tags: power, brushless-dc-motor, three-phase, labview

From https://www.studyforfe.com/blog/steps-for-solving-the-two-method-wattmeter-problem/ :

$$\begin{aligned}
   W_1 &= V_L \cdot I_L \cdot \cos(30°+\phi) \\
   W_2 &= V_L \cdot I_L \cdot \cos(30°-\phi) \\
     P &= \sqrt{3} \cdot V_L \cdot I_L \cdot \cos(\phi) \\
(\phi) &= \tan^{-1} \left[ \sqrt{3} \frac{W_2-W_1}{W_1+W_2} \right]
\end{aligned}$$

This notation is a bit confusing because using \$V_L\$ and \$I_L\$ for line voltage and line current it seems like only one watt meter is actually needed? Also, I am assuming that I should be using RMS voltage and current for all of these calculations?

My current labview implementation looks like this:
[image: Labview schematic]

But powering the ESC with a DC bench-top power supply I know that I am supplying only 88W while this logic measures 120W, about twice what I would expect if my ESC is ~65% efficient.

Any tips appreciated

Comment: I wouldn't base anything on that site because they say *The Two-Wattmeter Method is a technique used to measure the power consumed by a balanced three-phase load* and that is untrue; it works with balanced and unbalanced loads.

Answer (score 0):

You're taking RMS values before doing the multiplication to compute power. That's not right.

Power is computed by taking instantaneous voltages and currents, multiplying them, and *then* computing the RMS value.

By computing RMS prematurely, the relative phase between voltage and current is lost, and the power computation will only work out if there's either no reactive power or no real power. And then you still won't know whether the power you read is real or reactive - only that the numerical value is correct.

Comment: That isn't true either; after instantaneous voltage and current are multiplied, computed power is the average value. RMS isn't needed at all. But, what the OP is describing pictorially is Vms times Irms x power_factor (that works for pure sinewaves only. And, this has got nothing to do with wattmeters and how they work.

Comment: Is that the only issue? Is this the correct way to calculate phase angle and power factor? Is the phase angle something I can determine from how the BLDC motor is built? (for instance, it has 7 poles, 2*pi/7?